# Read data written by HttpWebrequest connected to tcplistener via tcpclient c#

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, tcpclient, tcplistener

I am having a bit of an issue is reading data posted from Client to the Server.
To explain the server code
I have created a TCP listener and it keeps listening for any client a while loop.
ie., via the below code

```
    listener = new TcpListener("127.0.0.1",3148);
    TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();//This code is called\hit when HttpWebrequest.GetrequestStream is called.
```

But When I do Client.GetStream() - I do not get any data in it.
i.e., NetworkStream stream = Client.GetStream() - No dataavailable in network stream

Here is the Client Code :

```
  Webrequest request = (HttpWebrequest)Webrequest.Create("http://127.0.0.1:3148/MovieData") ;
  NetworkStream stream = request.GetRequestStream()

 string Header = "\r\n Content-Type:MovieData \r\n";
 byte[] headerbyte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);
 stream.Write(headerbyte,0,headerbyte.Length);
 stream.close();
```

Am I missing something here , Is there anything conceptually missing in my implementation.
The Server and client are connect to same port and host, but the data written in the networkstream in client side could not be read by server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless these are custom classes change the spelling like this.

From this:

```
Webrequest request = (HttpWebrequest)Webrequest.Create("http://127.0.0.1:3148/MovieData")
```

To this:

```
WebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://127.0.0.1:3148/MovieData")
```

If you are tying to communicate over tcp between a client and a server try only using tcpClient and not WebRequest. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-client-socket-example) and [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/synchronous-server-socket-example) are some examples on how to implement that.

It looks like you have a tcp Socket open and are trying to connect to it using Http. Instead try connecting to your tcp Socket using tcp like this:

```
TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
tcpclnt.Connect("http://127.0.0.1", 3148);
```

You would then use `tcpclnt` to send and receive data between the client and server

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.connect?view=net-6.0) is a link on how `tcpclnt.Connect()` works

Comment: Thanks Dylan. But, I want to Communicate using HTTPWEBREQUEST(Client) to TCPlistener SERVER -> is that possible or I am missing something?

Comment: Hey @KarthiJayaprakasam! A very important detail in your code is that you are trying to connect to a TCPlistenver(Server) using an HTTPWEBREQUEST(client). The issue here is that your server is only listening for TCP connections and your client is only giving HTTP connections. Unless these two protocols match it will be difficult to communicate like this. Do you have a webserver running on your computer on port 3148?

Comment: Hi Dylan, Yes. Tcp actually accepts the tcpclient when I hit the http url using with the same host and port.